# Mount linux folder to another remote linux machine

Tags: java, linux, mount

I want to mount a linux folder (machine A) to another remote linux machine (machine B). The linux folder from machine A contains large files (in gigabytes) which are needed by machine B. It is easy to do it using the terminal, but what I need is, to do it using Java. The Java program is placed in machine A. What I have in mind is, I will use SSH Java API to connect to machine B, and execute the necessary mount commands. However, I'm not sure if this will work or if there are other better solutions.

Comment: _However, I'm not sure if this will work or if there are other better solutions._ It should work but i think you'll need to have permissions to mount

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically or by running linux commands?

Comment: I want this done programmatically